# From git to deb repo

Tags: git, svn, repository, deb

I have a Git repo that has all the neccessary files for deb repo, the whole neccessary structure and files.
Now I want to get those files from git repository (for example branch "new") to my webserver/deb repo.

What's the best way to do it?
I used to use SVN and just used the SVN export command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent in Git of the `svn export` command, so probably the easiest way is to make an archive and unpack it. `git archive` makes a ZIP or tar archive containing just the contents of the repository without any of Git's metadata, so make one of those and unpack it:

```
git archive -o /tmp/repo.tar HEAD
cd /your/server/directory
tar -xf /tmp/repo.tar
rm /tmp/repo.tar
```

You can avoid the temporary file with the `-C` option to tell `tar` to change directory:

```
git archive --format tar HEAD | tar -C /your/server/directory -xf -
```

The `-f -` tells `tar` to take its input from stdin.

Perhaps one day Git will acquire the ability to archive to a file tree, like `svn export` or `hg archive --type files`.